# ONFOCUS event alert calling multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history, onfocus

Hi Please find the below code and help to resolve the issue

```
<html>
<body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function fnAlertTitle(){
    var strTitleFlag =document.test.fname.value.trim();
    console.log("strTitleFlag::"+strTitleFlag);
    if (strTitleFlag == "") {
            alert("Please Select Fname");
            document.test.fname.focus();
            window.event.returnValue =false;
            return;
        }
}
$('body').on('keydown', 'input, select', function(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        var self = $(this), form = self.parents('form:eq(0)'), focusable, next;
        focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
        next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this)+1);
        if (next.length) {
            next.focus();
        } else {
            form.submit();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
</script>
<h1>The input element</h1>
<form  name="test" action="">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" tabindex="1"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" tabindex="2" onFocus="javascript:fnAlertTitle();"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Pressing tab ONFOCUS event calling once but while pressing enter its calling multiple times please help to resolve the issue

Comment: use `console.log` instead of `alert`. Opening a popup automatically switches the focus (and thus ends up triggering itself again) - you're also switching it manually yourself *as well* within `fnAlertTitle()`.

Comment: Hi function fnAlertTitle() calling 3 times

Comment: Yes, use `console.log` instead of `alert()` for testing (F12 to open console); and turn off both your `onFocus=..` and `fname.focus()`. They're both a bad idea and combining them with an `alert` is even worse. Focus isn't something you play around with like that. If you want to get whats going on then add some `console.log('foobar');` statements into both the events you're currently listening for and into the `fnAlertTitle` function. You'll be able to get a better picture of the problem then.

Comment: Hi @Raxi Thanks for your response While using `console.log`  no issue but my requirement need to use Alert

Comment: Ah, well that's fine, but don't use it in combination with hooks on the `onfocus` event while having that (re)trigger the `alert()`. That's never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove **onFocus="javascript:fnAlertTitle();"** from HTML and make smaller changes to your code as bellow:

```
function fnAlertTitle(){
    ...
    if (strTitleFlag == "") {
        ...
        return true;
    }
}

$('body').on('keydown', 'input, select', function(e) {

   if (e.key === "Enter") {
    if(fnAlertTitle()) return;
    
    var self = ...
   }
});
```